# Setup header before call webservice

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, apache-axis, wsdl2java

I've generate a web service client with Eclipse.
Now I need to add username and password inside the header for authentication bud not work.

This is my source code:

```
    ....
    ....
    org.apache.axis.client.Call _call = createCall();

    _call.setOperation(_operations[2]);
    _call.setUseSOAPAction(true);
    _call.setSOAPActionURI("");
    _call.setEncodingStyle(null);
    _call.setProperty(org.apache.axis.client.Call.SEND_TYPE_ATTR, Boolean.FALSE);
    _call.setProperty(org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.PROP_DOMULTIREFS, Boolean.FALSE);
    _call.setSOAPVersion(org.apache.axis.soap.SOAPConstants.SOAP11_CONSTANTS);
    _call.setOperationName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://uploadservice.xyz.it/", "ListFatturaPA"));

    _call.setProperty("username","xyz");
    _call.setProperty("password","xyz");


    setRequestHeaders(_call);
    setAttachments(_call);
    ....
    ....
```

Where is the problem?

Carlo

Answer (score 0):

"username" and "password" are wrong keys.
Use the given methods instead.

Change

```
_call.setProperty("username","xyz");
_call.setProperty("password","xyz");
```

to

```
_call.setUsername("xyz");
_call.setPassword("xyz");
```

Source: 
https://axis.apache.org/axis/java/apiDocs/org/apache/axis/client/Call.html

Comment: Thanks Fabian bud not work.
I need to add two generic properties inside call header: 'username' and 'password'

This is screenshot of SoapUI test: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/74145437/soapui.jpg